# Cannot add systemd-analyze to Buildroot image

Tags: embedded-linux, systemd, buildroot

I decided to use systemd in my embedded linux system to be able to use systemd-analyze tool. I can add both systemd and systemd-analyze in my config, but after runing my system on Raspberry Pi 4, I can't run `systemd-analyze` (command not found). Do I need to add something else to make this work or configure something?

Comment: make sure your rootfs image has the systemd-analyze binary . If not add this to your rootfs image.

Comment: There is no binary, the problem is that I can mark systemd-analyze to install on rootfs, but after `make` this doesn't exist. Maybe I should try `make clean all` instead, but I abandoned resolving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same situation but I built my Linux system in 2 times:

1. with Buildroot 'systemd-analyze' option turned OFF (no `systemd-analyze`).
2. with this option turned ON: nothing more...

The solution came from rebuilding the `systemd` package:

```
make systemd-dirclean
make
```

(`make systemd-reconfigure` may be sufficient? I didn't test it.)

After that, `systemd-analyze` was found in its regular directory (`/bin/systemd-analyze`).